# Who should I ask for a raise?

Tags: company-culture, raise

I've been reading a lot of questions & answers about **how** to ask for a raise, but now I would really love to know whom I should ask to.

To give you a little insight on the company I'm working for:

- The company is German
- I work in the HQ in Germany
- A total of ~5000 people work in the whole company (~2000 in the HQ)
- HQ is divided in buildings, which are scattered around the city
- The building where I work is basically the R&D one, HR is in another building
- I don't have any person working under me
- My leader reports to his boss, which is the head of R&D
- The head of R&D reports to the management

Should I sit with my leader and discuss the possibility of a raise, should I directly involve the HR, or do I need to consult the R&D head?

Comment: Ask your chef ("vorgesetzter") most of the time either its him or his Boss or HR directly which I doubt since negotiating with 5000 People is madness for an HR department.

Comment: Company-specific.

Comment: Is your leader in a position to grant you a raise? If so, he's the one to ask.

Comment: Please pardon me if the question seems badly formulated, but I don't think this is "company specific". I believe there are formal ways that are more or less equal in all the big companies, and I also think that there are figures that one might speak to, in order to ask. I don't know if my leader can grant me a raise (I don't believe so, since we have an HR office).

Answer (score 2):

There is no set structure for companies, not even in Germany. Ask your direct supervisor ("Direkter Vorgesetzter" / "Disziplinarischer Vorgesetzter") he will now how to handle this.

Don't do this in public. Take him aside, ask for a one-on-one or wait for the next one if one is already scheduled.